# Serializing RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD which I am trying to serialize and then reconstruct by deserializing. I am trying to see if this is possible in Apache Spark.

```
     static JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        static SerializerInstance si = SparkEnv.get().closureSerializer().newInstance();
    static ClassTag<JavaRDD<String>> tag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(JavaRDD.class);
..
..
            JavaRDD<String> rdd = sc.textFile(logFile, 4);
            System.out.println("Element 1 " + rdd.first());
            ByteBuffer bb= si.serialize(rdd, tag);
            JavaRDD<String> rdd2 = si.deserialize(bb, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),tag);
            System.out.println(rdd2.partitions().size());
            System.out.println("Element 0 " + rdd2.first());
```

I get an exception on the last line when I perform an action on the newly created RDD. The way I am serializing is similar to how it is done internally in Spark.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(x => rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.sc(RDD.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1177)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1189)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.first(JavaRDDLike.scala:477)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.first(JavaRDD.scala:32)
    at SimpleApp.sparkSend(SimpleApp.java:63)
    at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.java:91)
```

The RDD is created and loaded within the same process, so I don't understand how this error happens.

Comment: This seems like overkill, why not just use Kryo serialization and be done with it? Then you won't have to worry about it. If not, I think you need to include the code you are omitting, such as how list1 is created

Comment: I've actually never heard of Kyro Serialization. Any chance you could provide an example of how to use it? I can update my code to show how the list gets created.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm the author of this warning message.

Spark does not support performing actions and transformations on copies of RDDs that are created via deserialization.  RDDs are serializable so that certain methods on them can be invoked in executors, but end users shouldn't try to manually perform RDD serialization.

When an RDD is serialized, it loses its reference to the SparkContext that created it, preventing jobs from being launched with it (see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a38774b8892a85184520078a2187e9ce2a190038/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L79)).  In earlier versions of Spark, your code would result in a NullPointerException when Spark tried to access the private, null `RDD.sc` field.

This error message was worded this way because users were frequently running into confusing NullPointerExceptions when trying to do things like `rdd1.map { _ => rdd2.count() }`, which caused actions to be invoked on deserialized RDDs on executor machines.  I didn't anticipate that anyone would try to manually serialize / deserialize their RDDs on the driver, so I can see how this error message could be slightly misleading.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insights! Your explanation clarifies my question. Perhaps, you might be able to provide an alternative solution for my end goal. For the purpose of my project, I am trying to take the RDD and the function to be applied on the RDD, serialize them and send them to other drivers. Is there anyway I can use the serialized RDD and serialized function to obtain the expected result? Since this is how its done in the executor, I am assuming it can be done by sending the serialized data to the driver as well?

Comment: Spark does not support sharing of RDDs between different SparkContexts.  If you'd like to exchange data between different Spark systems, consider persisting that data to a filesystem or storing it in a system like Tachyon.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I understand that I can persist an RDD in storage, but I am not sure how to create another RDD using that persisted RDD. Any chance you could provide an example of this?

Comment: Also, you mentioned that the rdd is serialized and sent to executors. When tasks are run on executors, within ResultTask.scala, the run() method uses this serialized rdd and the serialized action function to compute the result of the action. So, I assumed that I can do something similar and send the serialized rdd and function to a java program and have it compute the results. The way it is done in ResultTask.scala does not seem like there is any Executor specific context that is being used. Is there a specific reason why this can't be done?

Comment: Certain RDD methods, like `compute()`, can be run on executors, while other methods, such as `collect()`, are only intended to be invoked from the driver.  If you're interested in persisting an RDD's data and restoring it from that data, look into the various options for saving and loading data into Spark (e.g. saving and loading text files, Parquet or Avro files, etc).  You can't simply pass the RDD handle between programs because data structures that it refers to are tied to the SparkContext that created it (such as broadcast variables, block manager entries, etc).