# Adding new members to RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am working on a research project for which I am modifying certain aspects of Spark to meet my end goals.

I am trying to add new member variables to the RDD.scala class, and then access those variables when the rdd is accessed from the worker node(executors). In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567247/serializing-rdd) answer one of the spark contributors mention that only certain methods of the RDD can be invoked in executors. So, I am wondering how exactly can I add new member field to RDD.scala so that it can be accessed within the executor?

Answer (score 0):

What about add those variables into your RDD's `Partition` class?

You know, in spark, task are not directly map to a single RDD's transformation, it may be a combination of several RDDs'. Therefore, what you want executor access is quite obscure, I would assume you want variables accessible to RDD's `compute(part: Partition, context: TaskContext)` method, which is executed in executors.

As the `compute` signature explains, it would only get `Partition` & `TaskContext`, given `TaskContext` is related to several transformations and transparent to RDD, the answer can only exist in `Partition`.

`Partition` is created in `getPartitions` method which is called in driver, and you can override getPartitions of your RDD to return specific type of `Partition`.

Therefore, a whole procedure I suggest is:

1. create a `class YourPartition(rddId: Int, idx: Int, val your_variable: Any, val your_second_variable: Any .....) extends Partition`
2. override `def getPartitions: Array[Partition]` which return `Array[YourPartition]`
3. In `compute(part: Partition, context: TaskContext)`, cast part as instance of `YourPartition`, and use the fields you created there.