# Spark closure argument binding

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working with Apache Spark in Scala.

I have a problem when trying to manipulate one RDD with data from a second RDD. I am trying to pass the 2nd RDD as an argument to a function being 'mapped' against the first RDD, but seemingly the closure created on that function binds an uninitialized version of that value.

Following is a simpler piece of code that shows the type of problem I'm seeing. (My real example where I first had trouble is larger and less understandable).

I don't really understand the argument binding rules for Spark closures.

What I'm really looking for is a basic approach or pattern for how to manipulate one RDD using the content of another (which was previously constructed elsewhere).

In the following code, calling Test1.process(sc) will fail with a null pointer access in findSquare (as the 2nd arg bound in the closure is not initialized)

```
object Test1 {

  def process(sc: SparkContext) {
    val squaresMap = (1 to 10).map(n => (n, n * n))
    val squaresRDD = sc.parallelize(squaresMap)

    val primes = sc.parallelize(List(2, 3, 5, 7))

    for (p <- primes) {
      println("%d: %d".format(p, findSquare(p, squaresRDD)))
    }
  }

  def findSquare(n: Int, squaresRDD: RDD[(Int, Int)]): Int = {
    squaresRDD.filter(kv => kv._1 == n).first._1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem you experience has nothing to do with closures or RDDs which, contrary to popular belief, [are serializable](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).

It is simply breaks a fundamental Spark rule which states that you cannot trigger an action or transformation from another action or transformation* and different variants of this question have been asked on SO multiple times.

To understand why that's the case you have to think about the architecture:

- `SparkContext` is managed on the driver
- everything that happens inside transformations is executed on the workers. Each worker have access only to its own part of the data and don't communicate with other workers**.

If you want to use content of multiple RDDs you have to use one of the transformations which combine RDDs, like `join`, `cartesian`, `zip` or `union`.

Here you most likely (I am not sure why you pass tuple and use only first element of this tuple)  want to either use a broadcast variable:

```
val squaresMapBD = sc.broadcast(squaresMap)

def findSquare(n: Int): Seq[(Int, Int)] = {
  squaresMapBD.value
    .filter{case (k, v) => k == n}
    .map{case (k, v) => (n, k)}
    .take(1)
}

primes.flatMap(findSquare)
```

or Cartesian:

```
primes
  .cartesian(squaresRDD)
  .filter{case (n, (k, _)) => n == k}.map{case (n, (k, _)) => (n, k)}
```

Converting `primes` to dummy pairs `(Int, null)` and `join` would be more efficient:

```
primes.map((_, null)).join(squaresRDD).map(...)
```

but based on your comments I assume you're interested in a scenario when there is natural join condition.

Depending on a context you can also consider using database or files to store common data.

On a side note RDDs are not iterable so you cannot simply use `for` loop. To be able to do something like this you have to `collect` or convert `toLocalIterator` first. You can also use `foreach` method.

---

* To be precise you cannot access `SparkContext`.

** Torrent broadcast and tree aggregates involve communication between executors so it is technically possible.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I am pretty new to Spark and hadn't yet come across the rule you mention (or it hadn't hit home if I had seen it mentioned somewhere).  It was natural to me to think about "consulting" one dataset when processing another, but I clearly need to adjust my thinking.

Comment: Thanks for the added info.  I'm only about 2 weeks into learning Spark so I'm still trying to get fundamental concepts internalized.  Broadcast variable is probably just what is appropriate in some of the cases I was thinking I would want to pass an arg to a mapping function.

Comment: Depending on a size of the data you should pass it in a following order: argument < broadcast < join where arguments should be used where size is negligible,  broadcast when data is large but still can be handled in memory of a single machine, join otherwise.

Comment: This answer is a nice variation on the definitions of Spark internals.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you've spent augmenting your answer to this question - I've learned a number of things from this.  I think I have much better clarity now in how to "think properly" about a collection of Spark coding issues.  Now I just need to go delete some code and rewrite it. :-)

Answer (score -3):

RDD are not serializable, so you can't use an rdd inside an rdd trasformation.
Then I've never seen enumerate an rdd with a for statement, usually I use foreach statement that is part of rdd api.

In order to combine data from two rdd, you can leverage join, union or broadcast ( in case your rdd is small)

Comment: I had previously seen comments to the effect that RDDs are serializable.  I just found the answer in the following post to be quite pertinent.  I'm still left with a quandry in my mind about how to handle the general case of manipulating one data set against another (where they are fundamentally different types of data and don't naturally 'join', etc.)   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567247/serializing-rdd

Comment: I happen to be using an older version of Spark (1.2) which as mentioned in that other post's answer generates a null pointer exception when you try to do what I did as the SparkContext field isn't set after the RDD is de-serialized.

Comment: RDDs are serializable See [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) and [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f85aa06464a10f5d1563302fd76465dded475a12/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L77).

Comment: yes, it's true, my fault. The point is the trasformation inside an other trasformation. Thanks for the deep explanation