# An error occurred when writing a pickled representation of spark rdd to file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, rdd, pickle

I use the following code to persist a spark rdd.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
file = open('test','w')
import pickle
pickle.dump(rdd, file)
```

and the error message is:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o550.__getstate__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getstate__([]) does not exist
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:335)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:344)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I think a rdd is similar to a handle, and I don't have to save all data in hdfs for use next time.

so, the pyspark rdd objects could be persisted? if not, why? how to save a rdd 
object for accessing in anothor runtime using an elegant method?

Comment: [`saveAsTextFile`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.saveAsTextFile), maybe??

Comment: Since rdd is distributed, traditional pickling would not work. You could definitely pickle the collected data but that's probably not of much use for what you need to do. So, `saveAsTextFile` as @desertnaut suggested would be the way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered just saving as Pickle file using the **saveAsPickleFile** method available in the **SparkContext**?

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3])
rdd.saveAsPickleFile('user/cloudera/parallalized_collection')
```

From the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html)

> saveAsPickleFile(path, batchSize=10)
>
> Save this RDD as a SequenceFile of serialized objects. The serializer used is pyspark.serializers.PickleSerializer, default batch size is 10.

Answer (score 1):

`RDD` is a proxy for Java object. To serialize it correctly you'd have to serialize both Java and Python objects. Unfortunately this won't help you at all. While JVM `RDD` is `Serializable`, it so [only for internal purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29568136/8371915):

> Spark does not support performing actions and transformations on copies of RDDs that are created via deserialization. RDDs are serializable so that certain methods on them can be invoked in executors, but end users shouldn't try to manually perform RDD serialization.

To address your question:

> how to save a rdd object for accessing in anothor runtime using an elegant method?

- If you're interested in preserving data use one of the output methods (`RDD.saveAs*)`.
- Otherwise create `RDD` from the beginning - the cost is negligible as it is only a recipe.