# Is it bad to put an RDD inside a Serializable Class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

According to [this article](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html), when you use an object inside an RDD.map for example, Spark would serialize the whole ojbect first. Now, let us say, I have an RDD defined as member of that serializable class. What would Spark do for that RDD, would it try to serialize it as well. If so, how?

Following is an example code.

```
class SomeClass extends Serializable {
 var a: String
 var b: Int
 var rdd: RDD[...]

 ....
}

objectOfSomeClass = new SomeClass(...)
...
someRDD.map(x => someFunc(objectOfSomeClass))
```

Comment: It will just fail and tell you the object is unserializable

Comment: No, it does not. I have been using RDD as member variables without any problem. I am just worried if it affects the performance. As long as you don't try to use RDD inside other RDDs, there is no problem. In my case I am just using some other member variables of that class, not the RDD ones. I have now added an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serializing RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567247/serializing-rdd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re:

> I am just worried if serialization of the whole class, also involves serialization of the RDD inside it.

The code that you have shown does not need whole object to be serialized. Hence you are not facing any serialization issues until now. Instead of passing `a` and `b`separately, if you pass `objectOfSomeClass`, then I believe you would face serialization issue.

In one of your comment you have also mentioned

> I am just worried if it affects the performance.

This too does not come in picture unless you do any action on that RDD. RDDs are lazily evaluated only when any action is called on that RDD. That is the time when it will read and run the transformations. In your example I do not see any action in there hence it should not affect performance of your application.

Hope this clarifies couple of your doubts.

-Amit

Comment: OK, say if I used objectOfSomeClass directly, what would Spark will do with that RDD inside that class?

Comment: AFAIK, it should fail. Can you try that and post it back.It will help confirm our understanding as well.

Comment: @MetallicPriest  could you mark this as an Answer if it meets your expectations and answers question you asked.