# Dataset<T> null when passing it to a MapFunction interface based class Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**OVERVIEW**

I am working with Java Spark to compute huge amount of data. I am loading into a `Dataset` the content of lots of `.DAT` files called the `feeders`. These `.DAT` files contain among others fields, a timestamp (number of seconds spanned from the 1st, Jan of 1970) when such data **started to be recorded**. In here, every row within a file represents a second in time. Example of how a `.DAT` **file** when data started to be recorded 1546297200 (Monday, December 31, 2018 11:00:00 PM, GMT), looks like:

```
id & deltaRSTs| timestamp| 
              |          |
SQXCXBAXY4P-02,1546297200,825,2065,391
1,0,-8,0      |1546297200|
1,0,-2,0      |1546297201|
1,0,0,0       |1546297202|
1,0,10,0      |1546297203|
1,0,-6,0      |1546297204|
1,0,-4,0      |1546297205|
1,0,0,0       ... 
1,0,6,0       ...
1,0,1,0       ...
1,0,-8,0      ...
```

On the other side, I have another `Dataset` that contains information about some electrical device (in `.csv` format). The important part here, is that such device created a set of events (let's coin it with `EVT`) with a different timestamps (number of seconds spanned from the 1st, Jan of 1970).

I want to take all rows from the `.DAT`s files that fulfill with a certain temporal condition: *given an event, take all `DAT` rows such that `EVT(timestamp)` is in `DAT(timestamp)`* taking into account an offset to create a window, namely:

```
maxEpoch = DAT(timestamp) + rows_of_DAT
DAT(timestamp) + offset <= EVT(timestamp) && EVT(timestamp) <= maxEpoch - offset
```

Don't worry if you do not understand this completely, it is for the sake of giving some background. But it's necessary that you grasp the idea.

**PROBLEM**

I'm going to present the classes that I considered suitable for solving the aforementioned case:

CLASS `ReadCSV` (main):

```
public class ReadCSV {

    private static final SparkSession spark = new SparkSession
            .Builder()
            .master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");

        Dataset<EventCSVRow> eventCSVRowDataset = getEventCSVRow(".\\eventLog\\*.csv"); //events from the CSVs

        Dataset<FeederFileRow> feederFileRowDataset = getFeederFileDataset(".\\feeder\\*.DAT"); // all rows from all .DATs

        Dataset<ProcessEvRow> processEvRowDataset = eventCSVRowDataset
            .map(new ProcessEvTransformation(feederFileRowDataset), Encoders.bean(ProcessEvRow.class))

    }
}
```

Note in this class, when an object of type `ProcessEvTransformation` is created, I am passing as an argument the `Dataset` of all `DAT` rows.

CLASS `ProcessEvTransformation`:

```
public class ProcessEvTransformation implements MapFunction<EventCSVRow, ProcessEvRow> {

    private Dataset<FeederFile> feederFileDataset;
    private int offset = 40;

    public ProcessEvTransformation(Dataset<FeederFile> feederFileDataset) {
        this.feederFileDataset = feederFileDataset;
        // I did here, this.feederFileDataset.show(); and it was successfull
    }

    public ProcessEvTransformation withOffset(int offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public ProcessEvRow call(EventCSVRow eventCSVRow) throws Exception {
        String stdPattern = ...
        String rejectedFlag = ...
        Dataset<FeederFile> deltaRSTs = this.feederFileDataset
                .filter(feederFileRow -> {
                    final long epochTime = Long.parseLong(eventCSVRow.getEpochTime());
                    final long maxEpoch = Long.parseLong(feederFileRow.getEpoch()) + feederFileRow.getLineCount();
                    return Long.parseLong(feederFileRow.getEpoch()) + offset <= epochTime && epochTime <= maxEpoch - offset;
                });

        String[] rstDistances = getRstDistancesAndMinimum(deltaRSTs, eventCSVRow.getIncrements()); // whatever algorithmic procedure
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem here is that I am getting a `NullPointerException` because somewhat `feederFileDataset` attribute is being null. The curious part is that I am pretty sure it is arriving 100% defined, but when the `call` method is invoked it turns into something null or `Invalid tree; null:` (is the message displayed when printing it)

**QUESTIONS & CONSLUSION**

- Does anyone know how to pass successfully a `Dataset` as a parameter to a `MapFunction` interface class based?
- Why the `Dataset` is turning into something invalid when I pass it correctly? does it have something to do with internal procedures of Java Spark?

I hope I have been clear. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Best wishes, 
Thomas.

Comment: Take a look at [Why does this Spark code make NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111607/why-does-this-spark-code-make-nullpointerexception), [Serializing RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29567247/10465355), and many similar questions. Nested operations like this one, are in general not supported.

Comment: Did not help. Anyway based on my problem I decided that my best option was to use the ``crossJoin`` method of a ``Dataset``. In there I would count with all the info needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to keep all the data, I would recommend using the `crossJoin` method. Please be aware that this method is tremendously expensive.

```
public class ReadCSV {

    private static final SparkSession spark = new SparkSession
            .Builder()
            .master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        spark.sparkContext().setLogLevel("ERROR");

        Dataset<EventCSVRow> eventCSVRowDataset = getEventCSVRow(".\\eventLog\\*.csv"); //events from the CSVs

        Dataset<FeederFileRow> feederFileRowDataset = getFeederFileDataset(".\\feeder\\*.DAT"); // all rows from all .DATs

        Dataset<Andamyo> joined = eventCSVRowDataset
            .crossJoin(feederFileRowDataset).as(Encoders.bean(Andamyo.class))
            .filter(andamyo -> {
                final long eventEpoch = Long.parseLong(andamyo.getEventEpoch());
                final long maxEpoch = Long.parseLong(andamyo.getFeederEpoch()) + andamyo.getLineCount();
                return Long.parseLong(andamyo.getFeederEpoch()) <= eventEpoch && eventEpoch <= maxEpoch;
            });

    }
}
```

On the other side, class `Andamyo` represent a row with all the joined information of an `event` and a `feederFileRow`.

Example of the output:

```
+----------+--------------------+----------+-----+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
|eventEpoch|          increments|internalId|phase|    deltaRST|feederEpoch|feederId|lineCount|      mrtCode|
+----------+--------------------+----------+-----+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       46|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       47|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       48|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       49|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       50|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       51|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       52|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       53|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       54|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       55|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       56|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       57|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       58|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       59|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       60|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       61|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       62|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       63|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       64|MRT0000020611|
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       65|MRT0000020611|
+----------+--------------------+----------+-----+------------+-----------+--------+---------+-------------+
only showing top 20 rows

root
 |-- eventEpoch: string (nullable = true)
 |-- increments: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- internalId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- phase: string (nullable = true)
 |-- deltaRST: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- feederEpoch: string (nullable = true)
 |-- feederId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lineCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- mrtCode: string (nullable = true)
```

**CHECK**

The offset applied was 0. Check whether `eventEpoch` was in the range of `feederEpoch` plus its line count (normally 3600 seconds), as you may know, every row represents a second in time. See the example of how to check.

```
for first row:
|1564995646|[2, 2, 2, 75, 33,...|        11|    R|[1, 0, 0, 0]| 1564995600|      02|       46|MRT0000020611|

1564995646 >= 1564995600 and 1564995646 <= 1564995600 + 3600 ===> TRUE
```